# Get start and end date of quarter from date and fiscal year end

Tags: python, date, datetime

Given a certain data, I would like to know the easiest/cleanest way of getting the beginning and the end of the previous quarter.

For example, given the following date:

```
from datetime import datetime
example_date = datetime.strptime('2017-05-12', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

if the fiscal year ends in September (`month=9`), the result should be:

```
datetime.datetime(2017,01,01), datetime.datetime(2017,03,31)
```

On the other end, if the fiscal year ended in October (month=10) the result would be

```
datetime.datetime(2017,02,01), datetime.datetime(2017,04,30)
```

The prototype of the function would be something like this:

```
def get_range(date_in, fy_end_month):
  pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define two function: one for the getting the quarter of a given date, and another for getting the start and end dates of a given quarter.  To get the start and end dates of the previous quarter, you would just need to subtract one from the current quarter (with some handling of first quarter).

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_quarter(date):
    """
    Returns the calendar quarter of `date`
    """
    return 1+(date.month-1)//3

def quarter_start_end(quarter, year=None):
    """
    Returns datetime.daet object for the start
    and end dates of `quarter` for the input `year`
    If `year` is none, it defaults to the current
    year.
    """
    if year is None:
        year = dt.datetime.now().year
    d = dt.date(year, 1+3*(quarter-1), 1)
    return d, d+relativedelta(months=3, days=-1)
```

Once these are defined, we can define a simple function to get the previous quarter.

```
def prev_quarter_range(date):
    """
    Returns the start and end dates of the previous quarter
    before `date`.
    """
    if isinstance(date, str):
        date = parser.parse(date)
    year = date.year
    q = get_quarter(date)-1
    # logic to handle the first quarter case
    if q==0:
       q = 4
       year -= 1
    return quarter_start_end(q, year)
```

And now you can assign the returned dates to variables

```
prev_q_start, prev_q_end = prev_quarter_range('2-feb-2011')

print(prev_q_start)
print(prev_q_end)

# prints:
2010-10-01
2010-12-31
```

Comment: Note: need to add `from dateutil import parser` otherwise you get the error `NameError: name 'parser' is not defined`.