# In python, how can I find the start & end dates for a random quarter in the past?

Tags: python, date, python-datetime

[Get start and end date of quarter from date and fiscal year end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019099/get-start-and-end-date-of-quarter-from-date-and-fiscal-year-end) provides great helper functions to get the current/prior quarter. I'm unable to generalize the `prev_quarter_range` function to include a `quarters_ago` param that returns the start & end dates for a random quarter `n` quarters ago.

Ideally, I want a function named `get_quarter_start_end_dates` that takes in (`dt`, `quarters_ago`) and outputs (`start_dt`, `end_dt`). Here are some sample inputs --> outputs:

- ('2017-01-01', 0) --> ('2017-01-01', '2017-04-01')
- ('2017-01-01', 1) --> ('2016-10-01', '2017-01-01')
- ('2017-01-01', 2) --> ('2016-07-01', '2016-10-01')
- ('2017-02-01', 12) --> ('2014-01-01', '2014-04-01')

Answer (score 1):

With [Arrow](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) it's quite easy actually

```
import arrow
def get_quarter_start_end_dates(dt, quarters_ago):
    date_in_past = arrow.get(dt).shift(quarters=-quarters_ago)
    quarter_start_date = date_in_past.floor('quarter').datetime
    quarter_end_date = date_in_past.ceil('quarter').datetime
    return quarter_start_date, quarter_end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def get_quarter_start_end_dates(dt, quarters_ago): 
    months = relativedelta(months=3*quarters_ago)
    start_dt = dt - months
    end_dt = start_dt + relativedelta(months=3)
    return (start_dt, end_dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [arrow library](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (for date processing) is very good for this purpose.

- Get today's date in `tod`.
- Find the first day of the month by replacing the day in today's date with one.
- Suppose we want to go back `n=3` quarters.
- Then `shift` the first of the month back by `3*n` months.
- To get the end of the quarter `shift` the first of the month back by `3*(n-1)` months, then by 1 day.

---

```
>>> import arrow
>>> tod = arrow.now()
>>> first_of_month = tod.replace(day=1)
>>> n = 3
>>> n_quarters_back = first_of_month.shift(months=-3*n)
>>> n_quarters_back
<Arrow [2017-04-01T16:56:46.377079-04:00]>
>>> end_of_n_quarters_back = first_of_month.shift(months=-3*(1-n)).shift(days=-1)
>>> end_of_n_quarters_back 
<Arrow [2018-06-30T16:56:46.377079-04:00]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question and after some trial and error I found the following to work:

```py
def get_n_quarters_back(n_quarters):
    date_in_quarter = arrow.now().shift(months=-3*n_quarters)
    quarter_start, quarter_end = list(arrow.Arrow.interval('quarter',
       date_in_quarter,date_in_quarter))[0]
    return quarter_start, quarter_end
```

If you want to specify the datetime to shift back from just add the datetime parameter instead of going from now. In this case `ref_date` would be an Arrow object.

```py
def get_n_quarters_back(ref_date, n_quarters):
    date_in_quarter = ref_date.shift(months=-3*n_quarters)
    quarter_start, quarter_end = list(arrow.Arrow.interval('quarter',
        date_in_quarter, date_in_quarter))[0]
    return quarter_start, quarter_end
```

NOTE: The arrow documentation states that the end date is an optional parameter on the interval classmethod. However, in practice this does not appear to be the case because without it `TypeError: interval() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end'` is returned.